# Formalizing Russel's Paradox in FOL.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I think I understand Russel's Paradox and can describe it in natural language, but I'm having a hard time formalizing it in logic. Here's the tiny bit I came up with so far:

$($The set $A = \{X: X \notin X\}$ exists. $) \rightarrow (A \in A \leftrightarrow A \notin A)$

Since $A \in A \leftrightarrow A \notin A$ is a contradiction, the above statement can never be true if the set $A$ exists. This is the paradox and why they came up with axioms that ensure there are not sets containing themselves.

But this seems like it's just the final conclusion (if it even is formalized correctly?). How do I get there? How do I formalize for instance "Assuming $A$ contains itself, its defining property $A \notin X$ is not satisfied, therefore it doesn't contain itself" and how do I get to the contradiction $A \in A \leftrightarrow A \notin A $? How do I do the whole thing step by step?

I'm not familiar with axiomatic set theory, so if it is possible to formalize it just using propositional or predicate logic and naive set theory that would be the best.

I'd greatly appreciate some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: What is $M$? It seems like there are a couple of formal things you want to do: Thing 1 is to introduce a variable (Let $A$ be such that ...) and Thing 2 is deduce a conditional from a sub-proof (Assume $A$, deduce $B$, therefore $A \to B$).

Comment: @preferred_anon Oh I'm sorry about $M$, apparently I couldn't decide between $A$ and $M$ while typing it up. I edited it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this feel clearer to you? We begin with a statement:

$$\exists A (\forall X (X \in A \leftrightarrow X \notin X))$$
We want to show that this statement is a contradiction, i.e. that we can deduce "false" from it. First - why must such an $A$ exist? Well, your set-builder construct has this property. Why? Well, the definition of the construct is that

$$\{X\,:\,P(X)\}$$

means the set $S$ such that $X \in S \leftrightarrow P(X)$. So it's not really a justification. It's like saying "it exists because I say it exists".

Anyway, given $A$, we can strip the $\exists$ and are left with

$$\forall X (X \in A \leftrightarrow X \not\in X)$$

Since this is a $\forall$, it's a valid FOL-move to take $X=A$ and remove the $\forall$. In particular, we deduce

$$A \in A \leftrightarrow A \not \in A$$

This is a formula of the form $X \leftrightarrow \neg X$. It is an exercise to show this implies $X \wedge \neg X$, which (by the law of excluded middle) implies "false".

#### Alternative

We could rephrase your original statement with less natural language as trying to prove

$$\neg \exists A (\forall X (X \in A \leftrightarrow X \not\in X))$$

That's equivalent to showing

$$\forall A(\exists X (\neg (X \in A \leftrightarrow X \not\in X)))$$

So: let $A$ be any set, and *choose* $X=A$. We then just need to show

$$\neg (A \in A \leftrightarrow A \not\in A)$$

which (by the same reasoning as above) is equivalent to

$$A \in A \vee A \not\in A$$

(and that's just LEM). Read that backwards to get a deductive proof.

Comment: This cleared things up for me, thank you very much! Just one little thing: the last line of your presented Alternative shouldn't be a inclusive disjunction right? That would mean both formulas could still be both true.

Comment: @LinusDieLinse Glad it helped! It can be inclusive or exclusive (the logic I'm used to only includes a connective for inclusive or). The connectives are only syntactical - they have nothing to do with semantics.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a theorem of FOL (first order logic) in any standard system, where $\mathsf{L}$ is any binary predicate:

$$\mathsf{\neg\exists x\forall y(Lxy \leftrightarrow \neg Lyy)}$$

So, first step, just prove this in your favourite system!

Now suppose that we interpret the predicate '$\mathsf{L}$' as ... *shaves* ---, and take the domain to be the men in some particular village. Then our theorem tells us that there is no man in the village who shaves all and only those who do not shave themselves. Sometimes this is called the Barber Paradox -- but there is no genuine paradox here, just a logical theorem that there can be no such person!

Suppose instead that we interpret '$\mathsf{L}$' as .. is a member of ---, and take the domain to be the universe of sets. Then our theorem tells us that there is no set  which has as its members just those sets which are not members of themselves. Think of a set  which doesn't contain itself as a *normal* set: then we have shown that there is no set  of all normal sets. This is, famously, Russell's Paradox. And this time the label 'paradox' is perhaps a bit more appropriate.

(Why? Because, assuming we can understand the mathematicians' usual idea of  a set as an object over and above its members, ... is a normal set --- seems a perfectly sensible unary predicate. And it is a rather plausible principle that, given a sensible unary predicate, we can gather together the things that satisfy the predicate into a set. So it is a bit of a surprise to find, purely as a matter of logic, that there can be no set of normal sets -- our plausible  principle can't be applied across the board.)

[That's borrowed from P-t-r Sm-th's freely downloadable *[Intro to Formal Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl)* -- which proves the theorem on p. 312.]